# How to get sources of com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl

Tags: java, xml

I'd like to debug the JDK implementation of com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.*

I assume the sun's implementation is the copy of http://xerces.apache.org/, is that correct? If so how to determine what apache Xerces version is in JDK 1.6.0_65?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, upgrade to Java 7. Java 6 has been end-of-life for several years already, and is now no longer receiving even critical updates (unless you are paying Oracle for support).

Then, once you're on Java 7, it's very easy to figure out what files are in use - because the code in Oracle is (for all intents & purposes) the same as in OpenJDK 7.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Right now, java 7 is not an option. Is there a way for java 6?

Comment: Why is 7 not an option? If this is production software, you are carrying critical production risk. To answer your question, there is no way to know precisely what OpenJDK code (if any) corresponds to a given Oracle / Sun JDK, due to the way that Java 6 was open-sourced.